# Drawing a textured triangle

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, system.drawing

I have one image and three vertices with its position and its texcoord.

How can I draw this textured triangle in a picturebox?

This is an image explaining what it is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`GraphicsPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx) and a [`TextureBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.texturebrush.aspx):

```
// Create the triangle
GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath();
p.AddLine(triangleVertex1, triangleVertex2);
p.AddLine(triangleVertex2, triangleVertex3);
p.CloseFigure();

// Draw the triangle
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox.ClientSize.Height);

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b), TextureBrush t = new TextureBrush(myImage)) {
    g.FillPath(t, p);
}

// Finally, set the PictureBox's image
pictureBox.Image = b;
```

Comment: You are not have in mind the texcoords to map the texture to the vertex. :(

Comment: @Blau: Maybe a picture of the result you'd like would help?

Comment: I've added an image url to the question.